# 7zip: compress and copy to destination folder

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip

I am trying to do the following: command line compress a file from `C:\TestFolder\file.txt` (source location) and on the same command or bat file put that compressed file in (a destination folder) `C:\DestinationFolder\file.7z`.

My scenario applies to our real life point of sale system. We have an `.mdb` file that lives in a folder in the `C:\` and I need to compress and copy the compressed file to a destination folder in the `C:\`. However, we do not want anything to occur to the original `.mdb` file in the source folder.

Let me know if I need to further clarify.

Comment: Have a look here at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20225465/175063

Comment: @Leptonator Your link is about "extracting". This questions is about "adding"

Comment: @DavidPostill you are correct..  I was going the wrong way..  Try this and this will insure the arguments are in place especially in a Batch Script: `7z -t7z -y a "C:\DestinationFolder\file.7z" "c:\file.mdb"`

Comment: @Leptonator That's pretty much what my answer says ;) `-t7z` and `-y` are optional.

Comment: Completely agreed.  However, I like to insure that there is no failure..  We have to send reports to over 1000 customers a day, so I utilize complete overkill with switches, quotes, etc.  Cannot have any failure whatsoever.

Comment: @Leptonator Sounds like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming method :)

Comment: @Leptonator "If -t{archive_type} switch is not specified, 7-Zip uses extension of archive filename to detect the type of archive." In this we know it is `.7z` so we don't need to switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Compress and copy to destination folder

Use the following command:

```
7z a C:\DestinationFolder\file.7z c:\file.mdb
```

Notes:

- `a` is add
- See link below for the full manual for the command line version of 7z.

---

#### Further reading

- [Command Line Version User's Guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/)

Comment: If I create a batch file for this and create a scheduled task will I run into any issues if the user on the PC is not logged in? I have had bad experiences with scheduled task that is why I am wondering if this is possible.

Comment: @IsaiahMelendez It should be fine. Try it, and if you can't get it working ask a new question.